# Increment a variable with the previous ones

Tags: php, mysql

I try to show a curve with energy produced for a day. So the curve must always be growing.

I try to increment the variable "energie_journ" my mysql database with all previous.

Exemple:

Mysql:

```
ID           energie_journ
1                 5
2                 5
3                 10
4                 6
```

Desired result:

```
First energie_journ = 1, the second = 10 (5 +5), third = 20 (5 +5 +10), fourth = 26 (5 +5 +10 +6).
```

Bit php:

```
while   ($row2  =   mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    extract($row2);

    $datetime *= 1000;

    $encode_energie_journ[] = array((float)$datetime, (float)$energie_journ == null ? null : (float)$energie_journ);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should be _adding_ each row value to an accumulator variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go i have made the `sum` of previous values in the query

```
SELECT id,(SELECT SUM(energie_journ) FROM `table` WHERE `id` <= p.`id`) AS  sum_col FROM `table` p
```

just use the result of `sum_col` which i thinks is as per your needs

hope this makes sense

Comment: Thanks ! I use your method, this is faster !

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$energy_journ = 0;
while   ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $energy_journ += $row[1];
    // now save this value to an array, if that's what you are after.
}
```

And avoid using `extract`, it's going to give you headaches.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have MySQL calculate this for you:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  energie_journ,
  @subtot := @subtot + val AS energie_journ_to_date
FROM myTable, (SELECT @subtot := 0) subtots
ORDER BY ID;
```

The result will look like this:

```
ID      energie_journ   energie_journ_to_date
 1             5                  5
 2             5                 10
 3            10                 20
 4             6                 26
```